# PHP Admin Refusing Access

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting the following error when attempting to run PHPADMIN

```
   Error
MySQL said: Documentation

#1226 - User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour'
resource (current value: 3)
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1226): 
User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (current value: 3)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected 
the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your 
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the 
administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Please help. I have accidentally set the maximum number of access during one hour of one of my databases to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Do wait and run the SQL at commandline

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET max_connections = 0 WHERE user='root'; 

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: and in place of user will i have to write something else? i am quite new to MySql and PHP.

Comment: you can refer here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/

Connecting to the MySQL Server with the mysql Client